# Pass a variable from controller to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, models

I do a simple blog on rails.
I have a Post model and a Comment model.
When you create a comment, if comment is not valid, i want to show the error.
How do I do?

model Post:

```
#/models/post.rb 
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
   validates :title, :content, :presence => true
end
```

model Comment:

```
#/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
   validates :name, :comment, :presence => true
end
```

Comments Controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

View for comment form:

## /views/comments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any?  %>
     error! 
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

## /views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

How to pass @comment from the controller CommentController to view /post/show.html.erb ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't `@post.comments`, where you have all of the post's comments, including the newly created one, suffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `render "posts/show"` instead of `redirect_to post_path(@post)` in your `CommentsController`.

Comment: You welcome. Here I've just considered your problem of not being able to pass a controller's instance variable to a view. Take a look at Vapire's answer, you definitely need to declare nested resource for Post-Comments relation.

Comment: you have in mind in routes.rb? resources :post do resources :comments end.

Answer (score 2):

And/Or take a look at Ryan Bates Screencasts about nested models and resources:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources

They're Rails 2 but to get an idea how it works it's ok.

Maybe also interesting for you:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't redirect to `post_path(@post)` **if** the comment is not valid.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment])

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to post_path(@post), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: "posts/show", error: 'The comment you typed was invalid.'
    end
  end
end
```

and change the first form line in `/views/comments/_form.html.erb` from:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

to:

```
<%= form_for([@post, (@comment || @post.comments.build)]) do |f| %>
```

then you should see error messages when it fails to save.